# Php - check if an include or block of code has an error

Tags: php, include, require, try-catch

How would I go about checking if and include or a require has an error in it. For example, and include would try to be included, if that page has an error the page isn't included and a message is throw?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't catch a parse error in PHP in the same language environment (for obvious reasons).

One approach might be to run `php -l your_included_file.php` using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and then check the exit code. The `-l` (lint) argument checks that your code can be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using file_exist function, it check whether the file exist or not.

```
$filename = "/path/to/file.php";
if(file_exists($filename)){
   include $filename;
}else{
   include "errorpage.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trap parser errors.

However, if the code executes something that causes an exception to be thrown, you could catch it with a try/catch block.